# Using notify-send with a non-interactive ssh connection

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to be able to use `notify-send` to send popup messages from one server to be displayed on another.

I'm sure this is possible with SSH, but how can I automate it to a one-line command that doesn't ask me for a password so I can include it into a script?

Comment: I've reworded your question; hopefully this is what you meant to ask.

Comment: Yes Shadur. Thank you for rewording and for replying. Just a thought ( to be worded as a question). Is it possible to recompile notify-send/notify-osd to remove ssh authentication. How critical is it to not have ssh authentication.

Comment: "Is it possible" - almost certainly. "is it a good idea to" - almost certainly *not*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to use key-based authentication for the ssh connection.

On the sending computer, create a public/private ssh keypair:

```
ssh-keygen -f .ssh/notify-key -C "notify-send SSH key" -b 2048 -t rsa
```

The program will ask you for a passphrase; simply hit enter twice to create an SSH key without a passphrase.

This will generate a pair of files, `notify-key` and `notify-key.pub`. Copy the public key over to the receiving server via `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/notify-key foo@receiver`

**NOTE** This will allow anyone who has access to `notify-key` to log into `receiver` with your user credentials and no password checking, which is a little more access than you probably want, so let's close it up a bit.

On `receiver`, edit `~foo/.ssh/authorized_keys` ; you'll see a line saying something like

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAP6Mmqm+ylUEQa+NRassh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAP6Mmqm+ylUEQa+NRa {.......} MuieClE1nhb33EgQ== notify-send SSH key
```

To tighten this up, alter the line to add the following:

```
no-pty,no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding from=sender ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz...
```

This will prevent this particular key for being used for port forwarding, X11 forwarding, PTYs (making a useful login shell), or being used from anywhere other than `sender`.

Once you have this, you should be able to run the command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/notify-key foo@receiver notify-send "Can you see this?"
```

and use it in scripts as long as the user ID running the script has read access to `notify-key`. I recommend you set its access rights to 0600 and stow it somewhere secure.

Answer (score 0):

For using non-password access, generate a public-private keypair (`ssh-keygen` followed by multiple <kbd>Enter</kbd>s onlyand copy the public key to the host
with `ssh-copy-id user@host`.

After that you can just do a one liner:

```
ssh user@host some commandline to run on the host to send messages
```

and `some commandline to run on the host to send messages` will be
executed on the host.